# Data Merging Different Quotes into Separate Pages Indesign

Tags: adobe, adobe-indesign

I'm trying to create a daily planner. I want to take quotes from an excel sheet and merge it into my indesign project, where the end goal is for each quote to show up in separate page. I was able to data merge individual dates into the planner using data merge. However, using the same method, I am unable to merge the quotes into the planner. It places the first quote from the excel sheet row to all the pages.

Is there a different process for data merging more than one column into Indesign?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uU50o.png

Comment: Data merging is almost always about more than one column. Either I don't understand the question or you need to refresh the basics: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z1QV6R1y8Y0 Probably in your case it will be two columns, that means two variables date and quote. Put them in the two boxes and expand the layout (or just flip through it)

Comment: And show, how your excel sheet looks like.

Comment: Hi Yuri, this is what my [excel sheet](https://imgur.com/a/UWyf1ig) looks like. 
I created this sheet and then saved it as a text file. Afterwards I imported it as the data source into indesign. Just to clarify my request, I would like to insert each quote for each page. For example, January 1st date would match the  quote in column B2, Jan 2nd would match the quote B3. I hope that helps

Comment: The sheet looks neat. About the same way how a source data looks in those videos on Youtube etc. Have you tried to repeat the steps from the video lesson? It shows how to handle with four columns. You can do the same with your two columns. The only difference is you have to put the variables <<date>> and <<quote>> in two different text frames, not like in the video where they are in the same text frame.

Comment: And make sure that the TXT file has the correct format. Actually it should be CSV format with commas as separators between the cells in a row.

Comment: Here is my indd file and the linked data txt file: https://www.transferxl.com/download/08vQTg2N3h4KwT